# jQuery Loop though an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple object with some simple arrays. I want to loop through each item in the object and check part of the array. For example, if a '0' or a '1' then do something.

```
var formvalidation = {
 title: ['id1', 0], 
 categories: ['id2', 1], 
 price: ['id3', 1], 
 video: ['id4', 0], 
 fileTypes: ['id5', 0]
}
```

I've tried the following but I get the entire object in each loop.

```
jQuery(formvalidation).each(function(){

 //Gives the entire object. 
 console.log(); 

});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "loop through each item in the object"? If you are looping through each property, how will you know what to check? Are you going to execute the same checking/logic on *title* that you want to execute on *video*?

Comment: To loop through title, categories, price etc and check to see if the array had a value of 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what kind of processing you're trying to do with *each* property (see my comment requesting clarification).

The example below demonstrates how to loop through each property and extract the first and second value from the arrays you're storing. This example is meant to illustrate how to access each property and its values only - you'll obviously need to plug your logic in where appropriate.

```js
var formvalidation = {
  title: ['id1', 0],
  categories: ['id2', 1],
  price: ['id3', 1],
  video: ['id4', 0],
  fileTypes: ['id5', 0]
};

for (let prop in formvalidation) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(formvalidation, prop)) {
    console.log(`Value of prop, ${prop}, is ${formvalidation[prop] [0]}:${formvalidation[prop][1]}`);
  }
}
```

You could also use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which is a bit cleaner:

```js
var formvalidation = {
  title: ['id1', 0],
  categories: ['id2', 1],
  price: ['id3', 1],
  video: ['id4', 0],
  fileTypes: ['id5', 0]
};

const keys = Object.keys(formvalidation)
for (const key of keys) {
  console.log(formvalidation[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to say that the previous answer here isn't right, but I thought Id go with what it led me to as the answer in this case.

```
jQuery.each(formvalidation, function(key, value){
    if (value[1] == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }       
})
```

Comment: Good solution. I'm a **huge** fan of jQuery, but I didn't provide an example in this case simply because jQuery adds absolutely no value here. +1 anyway for those who are looking for a jQuery solution.